# Jakarta mail IMAP Could not download photo

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Jakarta mail could not read email photo

I don't know how to handle it.

InputStream x.available is 0 ,

Could not download source data

this is my writePart code

```
public static void writePart(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart content = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
                writePart(content.getBodyPart(i));
            }

        }
        else if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            System.out.println(p.getContent());
        }
        else if (p.isMimeType("image/jpeg")) {
            MimeBodyPart iPart = (MimeBodyPart) p;
            String imgName = iPart.getFileName();
            InputStream x = (InputStream) iPart.getContent();
            
            //here!!! x.available is zore,why
            System.out.println("x.length = " + x.available());
            int i = 0;
            byte[] bArray = new byte[x.available()];

            while ((i = x.available()) > 0) {
                int result = x.read(bArray);
                if (result == -1)
                    break;
            }
            //todo temp directory
            File file = new File("tmp/" + imgName);
            boolean b = file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream f2 = new FileOutputStream(file);
            f2.write(bArray);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `File file = new File("tmp/" + imgName);` - looks looks backdoor: you are accepting path and content from untrusted source, so everyone may override files on application's FS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to read an `InputStream`. The documentation for [`InputStream.available`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) states:

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.
>
> Note that while some implementations of `InputStream` will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

The key phrase there is "without blocking". This means there may be more data available on the remote side, so it's incorrect to use this to detect the end of the stream. Instead, you should check `result` (the return value from `InputStream.read`(bArray).

It's also incorrect to use the result from `available` to allocate `bArray`. It is not possible in general to determine the size of all data that will be produced by an `InputStream`. In fact, regardless of the size of the buffer, it is not guaranteed that all of the data will be returned from the `InputStream` in a single call to `read`, so there needs to be a loop that either appends each read to a dynamically-sized buffer, or processes the read data in a streaming fashion. The latter is preferable, as it doesn't require retaining all of the data in memory at once, which could cause heap space exhaustion for large attachments in this case.

Implementing low-level I/O operations correctly can be tricky, so it's better to use a high-level method when available. In the case of [`MimeBodyPart`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/1.6/apidocs/javax/mail/internet/mimebodypart), you can use the [`writeTo`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/1.6/apidocs/javax/mail/internet/mimebodypart#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) method to automatically write to the `FileOutputStream`:

```
iPart.writeTo(f2);
```

This eliminates the need to explicitly get and read from the `InputStream`.

Comment: Thank you for help to solve the problem. I am a rookie